# Ubuntu from scratch

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, source

Is it possible to compile each and every package (that come up with Ubuntu Installation ISO) from scratch and come up with home-made-compiled Ubuntu variant ?

Where I can see, what config parameters/patches Ubuntu has used while creating ?

On Ubuntu's site, for any given particular release, list of all packages can be seen. But I am unable to find it's compilation options.

**EDIT:** Basically, I would like to understand Multilib/Multiarch functionality of Ubuntu

*(If this question is unfit then do let me know, I will safely delete this question)*

Answer (score 3):

It’s possible; the difficulty level will depend on how strict you want to be.

Packages in Ubuntu (as in Debian and all Debian derivatives) are fully described by the files in the `debian` directory in the corresponding source package. To rebuild a package from source, run

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
apt-get -b source <package>
```

(replacing `<package>` with the name of the package you want to rebuild). You’ll find the compile options in `debian/rules`, based on defaults provided by `debhelper` and `dpkg-buildflags` (so `debian/rules` might not contain much at all).

If you want to rebuild from scratch, starting with a minimal system and working your way up without every installing a binary package, things get more complex. See [How to update all Debian packages from source code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184812/86440) for the basics (and reasons why you probably don’t want to do this).

To understand multiarch, I don’t think there’s any need to rebuild Ubuntu. Start by reading [the multiarch documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch); then if you need more you can look at [the patches which implement multiarch in GCC](https://sources.debian.org/src/gcc-8/8.1.0-12/debian/patches/) (they all have “multiarch” in their name), at the support for multiarch in [`debhelper`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper), [*e.g.* here for `autoconf`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debhelper/blob/master/lib/Debian/Debhelper/Buildsystem/autoconf.pm#L46), and at [the `ld.so` configuration in `glibc`](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/blob/sid/debian/rules.d/build.mk#L235).

Comment: That was very quick and prompt reply. I am having enough patience if the outcome is fruitful. Please see EDIT to the question